# i3 core performance problems

Tags: ubuntu, quake-3

I just tried to play Quake3 (QuakeLive) on a new laptop with an i3 core integrated GPU, running Ubuntu 10.10. Strangely, the performance was terrible. I'm running on intel driver, which seems to load correctly. I know it's not a high-end system, but I got used to Q3 being fairly playable on 3 year old built-in i850GM with single core CPU, which was obviously much worse.

After switching to i3, I get barely 5fps, even if I use very low resolutions (640x480 and similar).

What could affect the performance that much? What should I look for? There doesn't seem to be anything obvious in the Xorg logs, or my xsessionerrors.

Comment: Not sure why'd they'd migrate this here, this is a perfectly good superuser question

Comment: It's probably an even better fit on AskUbuntu. It almost certainly is a problem with the Intel driver. Since the whole KMS stuff that driver got really bad.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Considering Quake 3/ Quake live is a game, this was migrated here.

Comment: @Sath I can see the line of thinking "video game... fps... send it to gaming."  Problem is, this question is really asking: "wth is wrong with my graphics card?"  Not really a gaming question.

Comment: @tzen Will keep this in mind for future migrations/question

Comment: @Sath I think its tricky as this definitely straddles that line, unfortunately this sounds like you're going to need someone who __really__ knows Ubuntu to get a good answer to this.

Comment: @tzen True. My thought was that perhaps someone in gaming might know on this, and would be perhaps fit here better than being close/offtopic in Super User

Answer (score 2):

The intel driver was rewritten in a lot of parts when KMS (kernel mode setting) was introduced. Since then it has been very flaky, I've seen a few notebooks with intel graphics that did not even work anymore on newer linux distributions, that did work perfectly fine in older ones.

You should check with `glxinfo` if you're really using the intel driver.

You could try to use a newer intel driver and see if that fixes the problem, the easiest way would be to use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver). This is not an official Ubuntu package, there is a chance that you will not get a graphical interface after the next boot if something goes wrong. You should be comfortable to fix that from the commandline, if you want to try installing the newer driver.